# Using data from an user that is logged in with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a login.php that works and keeps the user logged in with session.
Now, User has an option to use his "money" to buy something, so he clicks on "buy" and it opens "transfer.php" which is this below.

```
<?php
        session_start();
        $servername = "";
        $username = "";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "";

        // Create connection  header("Location:transfer2.php");
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 


        $sql = "UPDATE user SET money=money-2 WHERE id=2";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

          exit();
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
        }

        $conn->close();
        ?>
```

Now, this part:`$sql = "UPDATE user SET money=money-2 WHERE id=2";` I want this script to automaticly find the id from the user that is logged in currently.

Im trying to figure this out, and I am just lost.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== true`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a weak, high-speed hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Answer (score 2):

In the login script, set a session variable to the user's ID. Then you can use this session variable in other scripts.

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET money=money-2 WHERE id = ?";
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION['user_id']);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        exit();
    } else {
        die("Error updating record: " . $stmt->error);
    }
} else {
    die("Error updating record: " . $conn->error);
}
```